# JavaScript get data-attribute multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-data-attribute

I have a problem with multiple divs and getting their data-attribute values.
All divs have the same class, and depending on which one I clicked, it should display that data-attribute value.

```
function playSound(e) {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  console.log(audio);
  if (!audio) return;
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.play();
  key.classList.add('playing');
}

function removeTransition(e) {
  if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return;
  this.classList.remove('playing');
}

const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
window.addEventListener("keydown", playSound);

const keysPressedMouse = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keysPressedMouse.forEach(keyMouse => keyMouse.addEventListener('click',
  playSoundMouse));

function playSoundMouse(e) {
  const keyMouseSecond = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyMouse.}"]`)
  console.log(keyMouseSecond);
}
```

https://codepen.io/hovsky/pen/dKQxBO

It works with keyboard, now I want the same effect with mouse clicking on different divs. I know there is the easy solution to use "onclick=function(this)", but I'm trying to avoid using multiple functions, and try to put them all under the same function.

the keypressedMouse selects all valid data-attributes and puts them into an object, but now I have a problem how to select the real one. Unfortunately, query selector selects the first element, so whatever div I press, only the first one is selected.

console.log(e) in playSoundMouse(e) function, display the correct DIV that is pressed and I can find the correct data attribute [image: correctly displayed div with a node value that is needed]

How can I access that node value and store it into a variable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split up `playSound()` into two function -- one that deals with the keyboard event, and one that just plays the sound. Then you can call that second function from the function that handles mouse events as well, since the two events look up the parameters differently.

```js
function playSound(keyCode) {
  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${keyCode}"]`);
  const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${keyCode}"]`);
  console.log(audio);
  if (!audio) return;
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.play();
  key.classList.add('playing');
}

function playSoundKbd(e) {
  playSound(e.keyCode);
}

document.querySelectorAll("div.key[data-key]").forEach(d => d.addEventListener("click", playSoundMouse));

function playSoundMouse(e) {
  playSound(e.currentTarget.dataset.key);
}
```

Comment: Solved the problem, But now the only problem is that only the border of the "Button" is div.key, not the whole button.

Comment: after some inspecting, i found out that the event document.querySelectorAll("div.key[data-key]").forEach(d => d.addEventListener("click", playSoundMouse)); is fired only if clicked on padding of that div, not the content of that div

Comment: use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`, so it will use the proper element when the event bubbles out.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem. Now I will go and learn the difference between those two.